# Compile time error in Charts library

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have integrated [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) into my swift project usind cocoapods. pod installation was successful and shows succes message as below

> Analyzing dependencies
> Downloading dependencies
> Installing Charts (2.2.5)
> Generating Pods project
> Integrating client project
> Sending stats
> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total
> pod installed.

The I opened my workspace and build the project then shows some compile time error in charts libary files (eg like, **Expected expression in list of expressions** in ChartAnimator.swift)

Then I tried to add the libary by dragging the Charts.xcodeproj to my project. Followed the steps given in the tutorial. No Luck same error comes in.

My Xcode version is Version 7.2.1

Am I missing something? or any additional configuration needed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: exect line of code where error is poinitng ?

Comment: Yes its worked in Xcode 7.3 Thanks  @Eric. If you write it as an answer then I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have updated your project to use the latest version of this third-party code.

But this code uses itself a more recent version of the Swift syntax, and your Xcode version doesn't recognize it.

You have to update Xcode and get the latest stable version (7.3 at the time of this answer), which comes with the latest version of Swift, in order to use the latest version of the library.