# Compiler errors in 3rd-party framework swift file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

This is a problem I've faced with some third-party frameworks as well but not all. I'm using Cocoapods to install the frameworks and then adding them through "link Binary with Libraries". Below is an example picture of the type of errors I'm getting. How do I get rid of them? I know the problem can't be in the framework since other people have used it successfully (I've seen recent tutorials).

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859249/compile-time-error-in-charts-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the framework is using older version of swift. Did you try to convert it to newer version. Try to convert it into newer version and then try to manually edit few of the remaining bugs. This is how you can convert it to latest version -

[image: Convert to Latest version of swift]

Hope it helps

BR

Comment: You're right, it did have to do with different versions. I didn't know you could update it through xcode. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help.